# In cox model, can the hemoglobin and homoglobin group be put in the same model?

Tags: r, regression, cox-model

```
fit.tdc <- 
coxph(Surv(t1,t2,status) ~ Hemoglobingroup + hemoglobin + sex + 
diabet + cluster(id), data)
fit.tdc
```

Can the hemoglobin and hemoglobin group be put in the same model? Or would it be silly?
my hemoglobin groups are made up of classes like Low-Low, medium-medium, high- high  belonging to hemoglobin

Comment: If hemoglobin group is just a discrete version of a continuous hemoglobin measurement then yes it would be silly in my opinion, since group is simply a lossy encoding of the continuous measure. The only situation I can think of that the discrete version might be better is in the case of non-linearity, but you would be better served checking this and using (eg) a spline to model non-linearities in my opinion.

Comment: then I guess if I create the model as below, if I don't look at the spline

Comment: fit.tdc<-coxph(Surv(t1,t2,status)~hemoglobin+sex+diabet+cluster(id),data)

Comment: Looks about right yeah. You should also look at model diagnostics, eg cox.zph